# task is to find the first element of an array that is not consecutive

Tags: java, unit-testing

Task is to find the first element of an array that is not consecutive.

E.g. If we have an array [1,2,3,4,6,7,8] then 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 are all consecutive but 6 is not, so that's the first non consecutive number.

If the whole array is consecutive then return null

Here is my solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class FirstNonConsecutive {

    private static int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    private static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    private static Integer[] arrtwovalues = new Integer[arr.length];
    private static Integer solve;


    static Integer find(final int[] array) {
        int[] temp = new int[array.length];
        int possition = array[0];


        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            temp[i] = array[i + 1];
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            if (temp[i] == 0) {
                temp[i] = possition;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (temp[i] - array[i] == 2) {
                arrtwovalues[i] = temp[i];
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (temp[i] - array[i] == 2) {
                arrtwovalues[i] = temp[i];
            }
        }
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrtwovalues.length; i++) {
            if (arrtwovalues[i] != null) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arrtwovalues.length; i++) {
            if (arrtwovalues[i] != null) {
                list.add(arrtwovalues[i]);
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.size() > 0) {
                solve = list.get(0);
            }
        }


        System.out.println(solve);
            if (list.size() > 0) {
                return solve;
            }

            else return null;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
      find(arr);

    }
}
```

This is my tests:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public final class FirstNonConsecutiveTest {
    @Test public void basicTests() {
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(6), FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8}));
        assertEquals(null, FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}));
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(6), FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11}));
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(11), FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11}));
        assertEquals(null, FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{31, 32}));
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(0), FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{-3, -2, 0, 1}));
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(-1), FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{-5, -4, -3, -1}));
    }
}
```

This test does not pass:

```
assertEquals(null, FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}));


java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :null
Actual   :6
 <Click to see difference>
Process finished with exit code -1
```

As it says: `Expected :null` and `Actual   :6`

But if I try that test-case with my main method then it returns 6 correctly and everything seems to work correctly.

**Why does my test not pass?** What did I miss?

Comment: " if i try it in my code it's return 6 and all programm work correct" -- If `FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8})` is returning 6, then your program is _not_ working correctly, is it? Your test is saying that it should return null.

Comment: In your code, null will only be returned if list size = 0. Also your code is a little too complex for what you want to do...

Comment: FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8})                                       in my code it' return null. But in test not pass:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is way to much complicated for this task. Try something simpler to avoid mistakes, like this :

```
find(int[] arr) {
    if(arr.length > 0) {
        for(int i=1; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i]-1 != arr[i-1]){
                System.out.println("The element " + arr[i] + " at the index " + i + " is the first not consecutive element of the array";
                return arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return null; //If we reach the end of the loop, there is no number not consecutive to a previous one.
}
```

Currently your problem is that `arrtwovalues` and `solve` are static. So when you run your first test, you enter some values inside them. And when you run your second test, they still contain these values so it returns previous value : 6.

When you manually test your code, it return null because you did not make the first test before, so `arrtwovalues` and `solve` are not already containing values.

Comment: thanks for the information, not think about static content. now i understand better how static is work

Comment: Even if they would be non-static it could still be an issue, they should be *local variables* inside the method.

Answer (score 2):

Because of this:

```
private static int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
private static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private static Integer[] arrtwovalues = new Integer[arr.length];
```

First of all, the variable `arrtwovalues` depends on the size of `arr.length`, which is always the same. Additionally, these values ***are not reset between the test runs as all of your testing code is inside the same method***.

Put these variables as *local variables* inside your method instead and use the `array.length` instead:

```
static Integer find(final int[] array) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Integer[] arrtwovalues = new Integer[array.length];
    int[] temp = new int[array.length];

    ...
```

This will solve that test-case, but you have one more failing test-case:

```
assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(0), FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{-3, -2, 0, 1}));
```

Which seems to be caused by your code handling `0` as a special case and returning `null` in that case.

It would be better to put each test-case in its own method annotated by @Test, like this:

```
@Test
public void basicTests1() {
    assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(6), FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8}));
}

@Test
public void basicTests2() {
    assertEquals(null, FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}));
}

@Test
public void basicTests3() {
    assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(6), FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11}));
}

@Test
public void basicTests4() {
    assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(11), FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11}));
}

@Test
public void basicTests5() {
    assertEquals(null, FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{31, 32}));
}

@Test
public void basicTests6() {
    assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(0), FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{-3, -2, 0, 1}));
}

@Test
public void basicTests7() {
    assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(-1), FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{-5, -4, -3, -1}));
}
```

Comment: I moved all fields inside the method, and get new exception:  ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, don't remember in which test exactly. then i changed length off all arrays to array.length as you say, you can see it in my answer, now all test pases, including: assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(0), FirstNonConsecutive.find(new int[]{-3, -2, 0, 1})); don't even need put each test-case in its own method annotated by @Test, it's work fine. Thank you for responding and for the information, code work fine now. and all test passing.

Answer (score 0):

You code looks complicated for this simple problem. This would do the job

```
public Integer findFirstNonConsecutiveNumber(int[] arr){

    int element=-1;
    boolean found=false;
    ;
    for(int i=1;i < arr.length;i++){

        int prev=arr[i-1];
        if(arr[i]!=prev + 1)
        {
            element=arr[i];
            found=true;
            break;
        }

    }

    if(found)
        return element;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: How do you expect the OP to learn by just giving them a better implementation without any explanation about what the problem was in their original code?

Answer (score 0):

replace all field in to the method itself, and past all test.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class FirstNonConsecutive {

    static Integer find(final int[] array) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Integer[] arrtwovalues = new Integer[array.length];
        Integer solve = null;
        int[] newtemp = new int[array.length];


        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            newtemp[i] = array[i + 1];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (newtemp[i] - array[i] == 2) {
                arrtwovalues[i] = newtemp[i];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arrtwovalues.length; i++) {
            if (arrtwovalues[i] != null) {
                list.add(arrtwovalues[i]);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.size() > 0) {
                solve = list.get(0);
            }else solve = null;
        }

        return solve;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[]{4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11};
        System.out.println(find(arr));

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Give it a try with the following find() method:

```
public Integer find(final int[] array) {
    Integer val = null; // 1
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) { // 2
        int current = array[i]; // 3
        int next = array[i + 1]; // 4
        if (current + 1 != next) { // 5
            val = next; // 6
            break; // 7
        }
    }
    return val; // 8
}
```

1 - Initializing the Integer variable "val" as null.

2 - i = 0 means that the loop will start from the first element of the input "array". "i < array.length - 1" means that the loop will continue till the second last element of the array or in other words the loop will exclude the last element.

3 - Current element of the array

4 - Next element of the array

5 - Consecutive means (current + 1 = next). This if condition is checking for the not-consecutive element.

6 - If the not consecutive element is found then it is stored into the "val" variable.

7 - Since the not consecutive element is found it is not required to check the rest of the elements.

8 - If the not consecutive element is found (6) then that element will be returned, otherwise null (1) will be returned.

Comment: How do you expect the OP to learn by just giving them a better implementation without any explanation about what the problem was in their original code?

Comment: Look at something better than what you have and you will automatically learn something better because you have already understood that what you are looking is better. Explanation is definitely helpful but a better implementation without an explanation is at least useful.